# How to parse these dictionary, tuples inside the list. I need a clear list output using PyParsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to write a sql query parser for some commands such that they show relations in the query i form of a list. But I'm using runTests() from PyParsing which gives boolean values and a line of output. 
How do I remove all the empty dictionary and tuples from the line of list.

I have tried printing table name or column directly for a single query but it doesn't print for that query. Please help me printing the output on a list so that I can get it in a csv file later.

This is just a small part of the code. I have referred sqlparsing from PyParsing github repository.

```
from pyparsing import *
ParserElement.enablePackrat()
delete_stmt = Forward().setName("delete statement")

LPAR,RPAR,COMMA = map(Suppress,"(),")
del_source = ((Group(database_name("database") + "." + table_name("table*")) | table_name("table*")) +
                Optional(Optional(AS) + table_alias("table_alias*")) +
                Optional(INDEXED + BY + index_name("name") | NOT + INDEXED)("index"))

delete_core = (DELETE + Optional(FROM + del_source("from*")) + Optional(WHERE + expr("where_expr")))
delete_stmt << (delete_core) 

test3="""\
    delete from abc where c=book
    """

delete_list=select_stmt.runTests(test3)
print(delete_list)
```

This is what I'm getting: I need the upper part but the list prints the last part that is the select_list starting from Boolean part.

```
  ['DELETE', 'FROM', 'abc', 'WHERE', ['c', '=', 'book']]

 delete from abc where c=book
 ['DELETE', 'FROM', 'abc', 'WHERE', ['c', '=', 'book']]

-from: [['abc']]
[0]:
['abc']


-table: [['abc']]
 [0]:
['abc']


-where_expr: ['c', '=', 'book']

(True, [('delete from abc where c=book', (['DELETE', 'FROM', 'abc', 
'WHERE', 
 (['c', '=', 'book'], {})], {'table': [(['abc'], {})], 'from': [(['abc'], 
 {})], 'where_expr': [(['c', '=', 'book'], {})]}))])
```

Comment: Don't use `runTests()` for this purpose. `runTests()` is for quick-and-easy testing of various sample strings. I think you just want to use `parseString()` to get the parsed results, then you can access the parsed fields by name, as shown in the indented output you get from calling `runTests()` (or by `parsed_results = delete_stmt.parseString(test3); print(parsed_results.dump())`

Comment: @PaulMcG The result now  I'm getting is in the form of a string and conversion of it to a list is not happening smoothly. Any other way I can get it in form of a list?

Comment: `parsed_results.dump()` is the string you mean, I guess. The `parsed_results` object itself is of type `ParseResults`, and can be accessed as a list, as a dict, or as a namespace. Try `print(parsed_results.table)`. The purpose of calling `dump()` is to help you visualize what attribute names are available. See more about ParseResults objects at https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html#pyparsing.ParseResults

Comment: I referred it and yes it is returning a list but in my case it is not happening idk why. `test3= """\ delete from abc where c=book"""delr = delete_stmt.parseString(test3); delete_list=delr.dump()   delete_list` **Output is in string form:**                                "['DELETE', 'FROM', 'abc', 'WHERE', ['c', '=', 'book']]\n- from: ['abc']\n- table: [['abc']]\n  [0]:\n    ['abc']\n- where_expr: ['c', '=', 'book']"

Comment: Now print out `delr.table`, `delr.where_expr`, `delr.asList()`, `delr[0]`, `dir(delr)` and `delr.asDict()`. `.dump()` is not how you access the results, it is just a way to dump out the results for you to debug your code.